# MockMVC test java.lang.AssertionError: Status Expected :201 Actual :404

Tags: java, spring, junit, status, mockmvc

I am writing test cases using MockMVC:

My method testing is following:

How can I fix it? What is the mistake? How can I write this test more easily? Thank you for help
How I can fixed my code ?

Comment: Are you familiar with [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)? The numbers 201 and 404 in the error message provide a good starting point to look at. The code is expecting the server to respond with 201 which means "Yes, I've created that for you" and instead is replying with 404 which means "I can't find that". If this isn't part of what you are asking you might want to [edit[ your question to provide more context about what your tests are supposed to be testing.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not tell me anything and it does not help because I still do not know how to improve the code

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to be an answer. Comments are used to get clarifying information or to make suggestions for improving the question. From your question it wasn't clear what you needed in an answer. I asked about your familiarity with the http codes to get an idea of where you were in the debugging process.

Comment: ok,
Can you help me fix this?

Comment: I don't use MockMVC, I ended up commenting because this question came through one of the review queues. I can try to help get the question ready so that someone else can provide the answer you are looking for. Please read the materials in the help center about [how to get the most out of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to run the test without the Spring boot testing support (you commented the annotation `@SpringBootTest`)

Then try initializing mockmvc as a standalone and passing directly the controller as an argument:

```
// mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
```

Comment: currently is bug 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: You should probably paste more of your stacktrace and also of your project structure, otherwise it's really difficult to understand what's going on right now

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)

Comment: at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)

Comment: project spring with gradle.